# htaccess consolidate root to url and hide index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have these two htaccess rewrites (which I culled from elsewhere) which function independently to do X or Y for my site. What I can't figure out is how to write it so that BOTH functions work properly.

**Redirect all requests missing "www":**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**Redirect all requests containing "index.php":**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

Additionally, the former function works to rewrite example.com to www.example.com. However, I have another site in a subdirectory on this root with its own "independent" url. But the function also rewrites that url from www.anotherexample.com to www.example.com/anotherexample.

How do I consolidate these into a single workable function without it rewriting my subdirectory site url? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have other rules in your htaccess file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep these combined rules in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Comment: That did it, anubhava. :) Thank you so much!